# Render WPF Window Asynchronously

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous

Is it possible to render a WPF window in the background and then display it? I have a window that takes 10-15s to load, and I'd like to not freeze the UI thread during the process.

Comment: This is not the rendering that lasts for 15 seconds but rather component/resources loading. Optimize this.

Comment: It's a third party control. Loading in the background seems to be my best hope.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't do that. The component has to be created on the UI thread, otherwise you'll be unable to insert it in your visual tree. You could create a separate window and run it on a worker thread with a dedicated dispatcher, but I suppose this isn't what you really want.

Comment: That is what I ended up doing. I appreciate the response.